# How to tokenize star ('*')?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to write an analyzer that will also tokenize stars ('*').
I've tried to write something like:

```
"test_analyzer": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\\W|_",
          "flags": "CASE_INSENSITIVE|COMMENTS"
        }
```

This worked ok for most of the cases I'm interested in. However, in case I have star it simply ignores it.

For example for:

```
GET test_index_06/_analyze 
{
  "analyzer": "test_analyzer", 
  "text":     "other_table*"
}
```

I'm getting:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "other",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "table",
      "start_offset" : 6,
      "end_offset" : 11,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

where I wanted to get also a token of *.

Any ideas?

edit:
Also tried:

```
        "test_analyzer": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "_|\\t|\\n|\\s|\\v ",
          "flags": "CASE_INSENSITIVE"
        }
```

but getting: [other, table*] instead of getting [other, table, *]

Thanks,
Regards
Nir.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Gibbs- well, in fact I've stayed with [other, table*] solution which is good enough for me. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason:**

`Pattern` analyser tokenises on non-word characters. Here `*` is a non-word character as `-`. Hence tokens are created without them.

To handle this with same pattern analyzer:

```
"test_analyzer": { 
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "_",
          "flags": "CASE_INSENSITIVE|COMMENTS"
        }
```

It results the below tokens because of default tokenizer, token filters of pattern analyzer.

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "other",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "table*",
            "start_offset": 6,
            "end_offset": 12,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want tokens at particular place, you have to update the regex/tokenizers.

Comment: thanks @Gibbs. But I also want to split on spaces. So for 'other table' I wish to get [other, table]. So trying to add the spaces, tabs and such.

Comment: You definitely can do by adding space character in the pattern. \s

Comment: umm, look at the edit in the original message. 
I wish to get the following tokens [other, table, *]

Comment: How about using `ingest` pipeline before indexing the document?

Comment: not really familiar with that. I'll read about that. Nothing I can do using the pattern?

Comment: I think you can use [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keep-types-tokenfilter.html). Type is a list of strings. You can add tokenizer on what. And tokenizer can be multiple so you can add pattern tokenizer also

Comment: I see. Ok, I'll try to play with that, see how it goes. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: Sure. If you get any problem, update or post the question. Don't forget to upvote if it helps and approve if it solves across the site :)

Comment: will do. Still struggling with that.

Comment: I guess that my issue now is that from one side I want the '*' sign to be used to split and from the other side also be part of the returned tokens. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Yes, before tokenizing you have to transform them by adding a token befor and after star. You can do that with ingest pipeline

Comment: ah, I see. ok, will try. Thanks again.